# Swift; Count cells in TableView with certain image

Tags: swift, tableview

We're trying to create a money management app. Therefor we have made a TableView in which the user can add their spendings. They can choose in which categorie their spending belongs, such as clothing, traintickets ect. We now have created a piechart in which we would like to display on which categorie the user has spend most of his money on. To get the data for this chart we need the amount of cells with those certain images in the table view.

So we want the app to count the amount of cells with for example the image clothing.png in it.

Comment: `To get the data for this chart we need the amount of cells with those certain images` No, what you need is to parse the data that has led those cells to have those images in the first place. Work with the data, not with one of its side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do that. Your data model should have that information. It would be a little counter productive to do what you're trying to achieve by counting "how many cells have a certain image".

For example, you could have a data models like these:

```
struct Expense {
    var category: ItemCategory
    var amountSpent: Double
}

enum ItemCategory {
    case clothing
    case entertainment
    case carMaintenance
    case groceries
}
```

You would create `Expense` objects like this:

```
let expense1 = Expense(category: .clothing, amountSpent: 10.00)
let expense2 = Expense(category: .entertainment, amountSpent: 67.49)
let expense3 = Expense(category: .clothing, amountSpent: 13.67)
```

Then, use this data to populate your cell images with the category and now you can simply use filter to get how many have `clothing` category and reduce to get total spent like so:

```
let clothingExpenseCount = expenses.filter({ $0.category == .clothing }).count
let clothingExpense = expenses.reduce(0) { (result, expense) -> Double in
    return result + expense.amountSpent
}
```